# Ошибка в модуле spdy-transport

Tags: node.js, npm

с недавних пор стала возникать проблема при сборке приложения на реакте. Приложение было создано с помощью стандартной утилиты create-react-app
При сохранении, периодически возникает ошибка
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

assert(index !== -1)

Новых модулей не ставил и ничего не удалял. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с HTTP(S)-2 и является ошибкой в библиотеке Node-SPDY. У многих проявилась после обновления Chrome. Подробности и временный хак, устраняющий проблему, можно посмотреть тут: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22986